# "ssh: connect to host gitlab.com port 22: Network is unreachable" error - can't connect to any SSH server

Tags: networking, ssh, debian, git

I have an issue I can't connect with SSH to Gitlab or any AWS instance.

It was fine before, but I remember that I have installed RabbitMQ last time (not sure if this is the reason). I installed it using this guide: https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html#apt-quick-start-cloudsmith

So, when I type any of these commands:

```
git pull //for gitlab
ssh user@ip -i key.pem
```

it will wait for 2 minutes and say:

> port 22: Network is unreachable

I tried to purge ssh and installed it again, I also deleted the trusted hosts files and stopped the RabbitMQ service, but it's still not working.

I tried with other PC within the same network and it worked fine. Also, firewall is disabled too, for both.